# grails field plugin <f:all bean="adress"/> renders string fields to zero length

Tags: grails, gsp

While trying to migrate from grails 2.x to 3.x I use a

```
generate-all
```

that generates a gsp containing

```
<f:all bean="adress">
```

for rendering all fields of domain-class address. On the resulting html Page the Integer fields of the domain class result in fields, where Data can be entered, the String fields result in zero length fields, where no data can be entered at all.

Is there a means to specify a length for the string fields in the domain Class. I already tried minSize and size in the constraints with no success.

Comment: My interpretation of the fact that there are no answers in 1 week is that there is no means to generate string entry fields automatically. That is in my opinion a loss of functionality from 2.x to 3.x. We loose the show effect of generating a CRUD functionality with some entries and klicks. I think that is an issue, that should be attacked by the grails authors.

Comment: despite of it, I will stay an enthusiastic grails developer.